# Node.js Download Manager

Tags: node.js, download, appjs

I have to build a download manager for big files (over 500MB) for Mac, PC and Linux.
I am going to use [App.js](http://appjs.com) to make the client program.
The idea for this manager is to keep the current download progress if the connection drops.

My question is how to make save the current download state/% and continue when the connection is OK.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you are OK using a library for it or if your prefer staying vanilla. But there is modules like `formidable`:

https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

It seems to be made for huge files and provide you a special event for watching progress:

```
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
});
```

Comment: I think this formidable module is for uploading files only or I am wrong? If I am wrong can you please give me some example code